# How many people know Flash's secret identity?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, secret-identity

So many people know Flash's "Secret Identity" in this new TV show,

> -- he is Barry Allen --

that I must confess I have lost the count. Below is a small list, far from complete:

> - Henry Allen, Joe West, Iris West
>
> - Catlin, Cisco, Dr. Harrison Wells I & II, Eddie Thawne, Linda Park
>
> - Jay Garrick, Dr. Martin Stein, Ronnie, Jax Jackson, Henry Hewitt(?)
>
> - Oliver Queen, Felicity, John Diggle
>
> - Captain Cold, General Wade Eiling
>
> - White Canary (?) -- I don't remember the crossover episode with Arrow/Legends very well...

Can anyone provide a complete list?

Comment: Everything besides for the line you put in spoilers should probably be marked as spoilers.

Comment: @ibid I have just done it.

Comment: The  Flash doesn't hide his identity, I don't think we need to either. Hell, the first line of the voiceover before the show is "My name is Barry Allen, and I'm the fastest man alive."

Comment: I like how 'He's barry allen' put in spoiler tag xD

Comment: From what we've seen so far, both Barry and Oliver seem to suck worse at this secret identity thing than Daredevil.

Comment: I think it's hilarious that Flash's "boring" secret identity is being a CSI, the set up for dozens of other television shows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Eddie Thawne mentioned in Season 1:

> So everyone but Iris?

basically everybody and their mother knows the "*Secret*" Identity of *The Flash* (currently, since the question asks about **how many** people know, the answer - depending on your definition of *alive* and *people* - is **26-28** individuums know it, which increases to **over 30** if you include already deceased people in the know):

- *The Family*:

> Henry Allen, Joe West, Iris West (& Nora Allen, technically, for all the good that information did her)

- *The Coworkers* (of the family):

> Eddie Thawne, Linda Park

- *The Girlfriend*:

> Patty Spivot (who figured it out all on her own, and didn't actually get a *real* confirmation from anybody, but called *The Flash* by his real name under her breath with her last words, so she does indeed know, and would technically fit into the previous category)

- The (extended) *Star Labs Crew*:

> Harrison Wells (Earth 1 & Earth 2), Cisco Ramon, Caitlin Snow, Ronnie Raimond, Jax Jackson, Dr. Martin Stein and his wife Clarissa Stein, Jay Garrick and the (maybe currently still locked up in the Pipeline, who knows really?) Henry Hewitt, Bette Sans Souci.

- The (extended) *Team Arrow*:

> Oliver Queen, Felicity Smoak, John Diggle, Lyla Michaels, Roy Harper, Thea Queen, Laurel Lance

- The *Villains*:

> Lennard (Captain Cold) Snart, Malcolm "I'm Ra's al-Ghul" Merlyn, General Wade Eiling, Grodd (do Gorilla's count?), Clyde Mardon (he at least saw *Flash* without the mask, but didn't live long enough to tell anyone about it), Tony Woodward, Zoom.

- The *Legends*:

> Cold, Jax, Ray, Stein (again), Kendra "Hawkgirl" Saunders, Carter "Hawkman" Hall, most probably (being from the future, and having *Gideon* as his crewmate, but as of yet unconfirmed) Rip Hunter -- so basically all of them **except** Sara Lance and Mick Rory.

Comment: Of note, Gideon has a different voice now, so it can be argued that it may not be the same Gideon or have the same databanks.

Comment: @phantom42 True, with Morena being busy on Gotham... different model or just different voice interface, who knows...

Comment: General Wade Eiling?

Comment: @DavidBanner- Dickish military type played by Clancy Brown- appearing in Plastique, the firestorm 2-parter,and the episode where Barry first faced Grodd head-on.

Comment: @phantom42 If i am not wrong, she was contacted for the role but rejected it due to busy schedules. Film/TV shows.

Comment: Does Supergirl count ?

Comment: @Oak Since the Crossover yes, so do James, Winn, Lucy, numerous DEO grunts, Cat  (who figured it out on her own) and so on and on and on

Comment: Joe's old boss figured it out.  Don't recall the character's name but I don't think he was listed above.